# Invalid Identifier on Update (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

I try to execute following command:

```
UPDATE DB_TEST.STOCK_ITEMS
   SET STATUS = (SELECT *
                   FROM (SELECT STOCK_ITEM_STATUS
                           FROM DB_TEST.STOCK_ITEMS_HISTORY
                          WHERE STOCK_ITEM_ID = DB_TEST.STOCK_ITEMS.ID
                          ORDER BY CHANGED_ON DESC, ID DESC)
                  WHERE ROWNUM <= 1)
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM DB_TEST.STOCK_ITEMS_HISTORY
                WHERE STOCK_ITEM_ID = DB_TEST.STOCK_ITEMS.ID);
```

But I get the error:

```
SQL-Error: ORA-00904: "DB_TEST"."STOCK_ITEMS"."ID": invalid identifier
```

I looked up the Oracle error, but all I get is that I supposedly used a wrong or missing column name, but the `DB_TEST.STOCK_ITEMS.ID` field definitely exists.

What other reasons can cause this error?

Comment: You can't update ONE column with a SET of data `SET STATUS = (SELECT * ... )` No database will know what data to put on that field. You may be looking for this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3034/42478

Comment: @JorgeCampos  . . . Read the query.  The subquery is only returning one value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle limits the scope of a table to one level of subqueries.  Here is a method that solves your problem using `keep`:

```
UPDATE DB_TEST.STOCK_ITEMS
  SET STATUS = (SELECT MAX(STOCK_ITEM_STATUS) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CHANGED_ON DESC, ID DESC)
                FROM DB_TEST.STOCK_ITEMS_HISTORY
                WHERE STOCK_ITEM_ID = DB_TEST.STOCK_ITEMS.ID
               )
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM DB_TEST.STOCK_ITEMS_HISTORY
                WHERE STOCK_ITEM_ID = DB_TEST.STOCK_ITEMS.ID
               );
```

Comment: Is the "OVER" a typo between "FIRST" and "ORDER"? It throws an error.

Comment: @Palmi . . . Yes, it was.